# Partially copy element from 1 object to another in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 objects (object2 has all the keys of object1 plus some additional keys)

```
object1 = {a:1, b:2}
object2 = {a:0, b:1, c:2}
```

I would like to update object2's values using object1's values. After the update, object2 will be like this

```
object2 = {a:1, b:2, c:2}
```

The value for key `c` is unchanged. Is there any way to do this in a compact way without looping through all key-value pairs in object1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign`. However, it will overwrite previous properties in earlier objects, so you need to pass `obj2` to it before `obj1`.

```js
const object1 = {a:1, b:2}, object2 = {a:0, b:1, c:2};
const res = Object.assign({}, object2, object1);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with using an third party package, you could use the `assign` method in [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash):

```
var _ = require('lodash');

object2 = _.assign(object2, object1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like my example below, it doesn't iterate trought object1 keys

```js
const object1 = {a:1, b:2}
const object2 = {a:0, b:1, c:2}

for(const prop in object2){
  object2[prop] = object1[prop] || object2[prop];
}

console.log(object2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with in the spread

```js
const object1 = {a:1, b:2}
const object2 = {a:0, b:1, c:2}
console.log({...obj2, ...obj1}) // output {a: 1, b: 2, c: 2}
//if you are using let you can do the following

object2 = {...obj2, ...obj1}
```